# Entity Framework Stored Procedure throwing "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'. 'Select' not found." error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a method in a class calling a stored procedure using Entity Framework, and it keeps throwing the error

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'.  'Select' not found.

However, I have the exact same method in another class and its not throwing any errors at all.

The method in question is this..

```
public List<ActiveAdministratorsForUpdate> GetActiveAdministratorByID(int id)
{
    List<ActiveAdministratorsForUpdate> lst = new List<ActiveAdministratorsForUpdate>();
    var query = from a in AAE.usp_GetActiveAdministratorsByID(id)
                select a;

    foreach (var b in query)
    {
        lst.Add(new ActiveAdministratorsForUpdate
                    {
                       administratorID = b.AdministratorID,
                       administratorName = b.AdministratorName,
                       administratorPassword = b.UserPassword,
                       administratorEmail = b.AdministratorEmail,
                       administratorRole = b.RoleName,
                       administratorRoleID = b.RoleID });
    }

    return lst;
}
```

What I am doing is moving moving some code around to work with another database that I added to the project.

**MORE INFO**

```
public virtual int usp_GetActiveAdministratorsByID(Nullable<int> administratorID)
    {
        var administratorIDParameter = administratorID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("AdministratorID", administratorID) :
            new ObjectParameter("AdministratorID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("usp_GetActiveAdministratorsByID", administratorIDParameter);
    }
```

Here is the stored proc

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetActiveAdministratorsByID]
(
@AdministratorID int
)
AS
DECLARE @ERROR_SEVERITY int,
        @MESSAGE varchar(1000),
        @ERROR_NUMBER int,
        @ERROR_PROCEDURE nvarchar(200),
        @ERROR_LINE int,
        @ERROR_MESSAGE nvarchar(4000);

begin try
    select 
       administrator.AdministratorID,
       administrator.AdministratorName,
       administrator.AdministratorEmail,
       administrator.LoginID,
       lup.UserPassword,
       roles.RoleName,
       roles.RoleID
       from [Administrator] administrator
       inner join [Login] l on administrator.LoginID = l.LoginID
       inner join [LoginUserPassword] lup on lup.LoginUserPasswordID = l.LoginUserPasswordID 
       inner join [AdministrationHistory] administrationhistory on administrator.AdministratorID = administrationhistory.AdministratorID
       left join [Roles] roles on administrator.RoleID = roles.RoleID
       where administrationhistory.IsActive = 1 and administrator.AdministratorID = @AdministratorID
end try
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ERROR_SEVERITY = ISNULL(ERROR_SEVERITY(),'');
    SET @ERROR_NUMBER = ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),'');
    SET @ERROR_PROCEDURE = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),''); 
    SET @ERROR_LINE = ISNULL(ERROR_LINE(),'');
    SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'');

    -- Test if the transaction is uncommittable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. Rolling back transaction.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;

    -- Test if the transaction is active and valid.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is committable. Committing transaction.'
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
        END;

    SET @MESSAGE = 'Error Occured in Stored Procedure ' + cast(@ERROR_PROCEDURE as varchar(200)) + 
                    '; Line Number ' + cast(@ERROR_LINE as varchar) + 
                    '; Message: [' + cast(@ERROR_NUMBER as varchar) + '] - '
                    + cast(@ERROR_MESSAGE as varchar(255))

    RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, @ERROR_SEVERITY, 1);
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Your Stord Procedure returns a single `int` result value, but you're using your sproc as a row-source. Please post the definition of your sproc, or just the signature line, as well as the signature of the EF proxy for `usp-GetActiveAdministratorsByID`.

Comment: @Dai, I made an edit

Comment: @Dai, I looked at the code for the one that is working and it is different than the one throwing the error, the one that works is     public partial class usp_GetActiveAdministratorsByID_Result

Comment: I deleted the class library and recreated the ef models and now it works